# Positioning jBar at the bottom of the page instead of the top

Tags: jquery, toolbar

I've been trying unsuccessfully for a couple of hours to modify [this script](http://www.toddmotto.com/jbar-plugin-the-jquery-call-to-action-bar) so that the 'hello bar alternative' appears at the bottom of the page instead of the top. I know it's probably not very hard, but my understanding of jQuery is very limited and I'm still learning the basics of css to edit the styles. The images would be fairly straight forward. Could anyone advise me towards the right direction?

Comment: Would you be open to a homemade solution as opposed to this one?

Answer (score 0):

First, since you want it to appear at the bottom of the page, you have to make it "fixed":

```
.jBar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then you probably want to use `.slideDown` instead of `.slideUp`.

Not sure what else would be needed, you can start with that.

Comment: hey Robin, I tried those suggestions but the bar fails to show up at all and the only thing that shows up is the jRibbon which appears still at the top of the page and slides up instead of down (which is what I assume the .Slidedown function was for). It's really tricky...tried similar things before as well.